# Dual Basis of a Polynomial Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let **V** be a polynomial vector space of degree $\le1$. The **inner product** is defined as:

$(v,w)$=$\int_0^1 v(x)w(x) dx$

The basis vector is defined as **V={1,x}**. Find the **dual basis**.

So, i'm studying linear algebra by myself and this exercise came and i couldn't solve in anyway. The most difficult to me is to understand why do i need inner product to find the solution?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dual basis of $\{1,x\}$ is composed of 2 linear forms $l_1$ and $l_2$ which satisfy
$$l_1(1)=1, l_1(x)=0$$
and
$$l_2(1)=0, l_2(x)=1$$

Can you figure out two linear forms which satisfy these conditions? What would $l_1(ax+b)$ be for a general first-degree polynomial $P(x)=ax+b$?

Comment: I still can't understand...

Comment: Take for instance the linear form which sends $P(x)=ax+b$ to $b$. It is easy to show that it's linear. Can you see why it sends 1 to 1 and $x$ to 0?

Comment: Sorry, but still no. I think that's because i'm studying linear algebra by myself and this may contribute to a non-understading of this topic..

Comment: Maybe if you do an example, a numerical example, i'll be appreciated.

Comment: @alvaro.louzi Hint: evaluating a polynomial $p[x]$ at some specific value of $x$ can be a linear functional.

Comment: Oh, now i got it!! Thank you guys...